# Add Image to Woocommerce catalog randomly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My clients want to have Images (up to 2 different) to appear on the Woocommerce catalogue page

Example: http://www.wildfox.com/whats-new/

They should be as a link and have a fixed gap between products.

I already googled the Web and Stackoverflow (also looked for Plugins) but I didn't find any solutions. Can someone help me on this?

Comment: The idea is to get your 'not working' code examined here. Your question is also not clear, what do you mean by randomly, is it just the mouse over change?

Comment: I tried hard to get something to work, but nothing did because I can't get the Hook right or what ever :S Its about the random Images which are in between the Products, and I can't get anything to provide me with this function. I am a newbie when it comes to hooks and filters and I didn't find any tutorials or anything.

Comment: Maybe it is not possible just like that. You should post your question to a woocommerce forum.